# C++ Library Cross-Calling

Tags: c++, dll, build, hyperlink

I'm not really sure if that is the actual name of what I mean, but you'll get it.

Supose I have 3 projects, 2 of them builds as libraries, and the other one as an executable. For my scenario I'll use *MSVC++* and the libraries will be *dynamic* (DLLs), and of course executable .exe, but I also want to if static libraries are also included.

And please, if I'm wrong on any of my assumptions, please correct me.

In the first library project, FirstLib.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <SecondLib.h>

#ifdef DLLONE_BUILD
     #define DLLONE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
     #define DLLONE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

int DLLONE_API MainOne();
int DLLONE_API InternalOne();
```

and FirstLib.cpp:

```
#include <FirstLib.h>

int MainOne() { return InternalTwo(); }
int InternalOne() { return 100; }
```

Similarly, in the first project, SecondLib.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <FirstLib.h>

#ifdef DLLTWO_BUILD
     #define DLLTWO_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
     #define DLLTWO_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

int DLLTWO_API MainTwo();
int DLLTWO_API InternalTwo();
```

SecondLib.cpp:

```
#include <SecondLib.h>

int MainTwo() { return InternalOne(); }
int InternalTwo() { return 200; }
```

Finally, in the executable project, main.cpp:

```
#include <FirstLib.h>
#include <SecondLib.h>

int main() { return MainOne() + MainTwo(); }
```

So when compiling the two libraries, I obtain the two .dll files, and two .lib files. Each library must have the other library .lib to link.

Then, the executable must be linked with the two .lib, and when executed, .dll should be in a known path for the exe, be the same path or some PATH.

Now for the questions:

1. Is doing this a correct aproach, or should be avoided?
2. Exe needs the two dlls, but each dll needs the other dll. Does each dll loads the other one again, or uses the same loaded version from .exe?
3. If they were static libraries, would each library be loaded two times, or just one? Or none of them?

And if you have a good resource where I can find more about this, it will be really apreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE as why would I do this** : Imagine creating an engine.

I have (just to be consistent with the previous scenario) a library called **Kernel**, and a library called **System**. Also a binary project.

**Kernel** has the code regarding program execution (main loop), handling, base clases and other high level things.

**System** has the code regarding HAL and low level code. OpenGL things, file IO things, etc.

**Binary** has the main function, and program specific implementation of the engine.

Why do I need that cross-linking:

1. *Kernel in Binary*: `main()` (*Binary*) calls `Kernel.Initialize()` (*Kernel*).
2. *System in Binary*: `CreateActor()`(*Binary*) calls `System.OpenGl.MeshCreate()` (*System*)
3. *System in Kernel*: `Kernel.Initialize()`(*Kernel*) Initializes the Kernel, but also the System by calling `System.Initialize()`(*System*).
4. *Kernel in System*: `class System`(*System*) inherits from `class Object`(*Kernel*)

**I know** i could avoid this circular dependency by, say, Initializing System from binary calling `System.Initialize()`after `Kernel.Initialize()`.

But then, *Kernel* will depend on no one, *System* would depend on *Kernel*, and *Binary* on both *Kernel* and *System*.

So my question remains in this case too

4. Is removing the cross dependency but to have this scheme a better aproach?
5. Same as question two: Does *Binary* and *System* both depending on *Kernel* as well as*Binary* in *System* represents double code, double loading or a performance or size downgrade or some kind of undesirable effect?

Comment: I wouldn't claim that this is an incorrect approach but it certainly is odd that you have a cyclic dependency between libs. Why is this the case?

Comment: I think it is illogical to have two libraries that call each other directly. But, you can use Callbacks, where the "caller" passes a "callback" to its callee.

Comment: why are they two libs and not one, when one cannot work without the other?

Comment: Use _interfaces_ instead of direct dependencies!

Comment: I have updated the question :3 Thank for your help guys!